# Não receber números negativos numa input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código: http://jsfiddle.net/ntywf/1987/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this).val();
        $th = $th.replace(/[-]/g, "");
        $(this).val($th)
        console.log( $(this).val());
    });
});
```

O que estou fazendo, é remover o sinal "-". Mas sempre depois não consigo andar com o cursos para o lado esquerdo, uma vez que a função está sempre a enviar o cursor para o fim dos caracteres. Como posso validar isto sem o cursor ser enviado para o fim da input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que podes fazer é o `replace` do teu último caracter inserido, verificar se tem o *KeyCode* ([Link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)) correspondente ao "-" (que é o 109), e substituir:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(e) {            
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 109 || code == 189) { //Enter keycode
       //Do something
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(valor.replace(/[-]/g, ''))
    }
  });

$('input').change(function(e) {
   var valor = $(this).val();
   $(this).val(valor.replace(/[-]/g, ''))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

**EDIT**

Acrescentei no código para o caso de o utilizador copie texto para a input, onde verifico se o estado da input foi alterado com o `change`.

Comment: obrigado <3 @CesarMiguel

Comment: não detecta ctrl+v ou clicar e arrastar.. (acredite , tem gente que clica num texto numa página e arrasta até o input de outra.. eu faço issso)  A forma mais segura é verificar o valor inteiro do input e passar um filtro toda vez que houver um foco no input e para garantir mais segurança, no momento do submit fazer novamente a verificação.

Comment: Sim, isso também é verdade. Vou alterar :P